# Global.asax code not firing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0, global-asax

I have as ASP.Net 4.0 application that I added a custom route table to in Global.asax. It was working fine for a while. I needed to change one of the routes to point to a new webpage and I did so in the route table but when I run the app - it still navigates to the old page. So I have been debugging to try and discover the issue and I have disovered two very strange things:

1) The code in Global.asax code is no longer firing. I set a breakpoint in Application_Start and then stopped the developement web serveer (VS2010) so that the app would have to restart and then ran the app - it never gets hit.

2) Even though the code does not fire - the routes are still there (pointing to the old page) - being cached somewhere?? I even rebooted the dev box but they are still there...

I scowered the app (team project) for any header files which can over-ride Global.asax and there are none. I don't know what to try next - any ideas?

Some new info - after googling around some more.

- Stopped vs web server
- Excluded Global.asax from project (Original code without changeing
  rout to point to new page).
- Rebuilt application.
- Ran application and now all the routes are gone - cannot navigate to
  any routed url's in app.
- Stopped vs web server again.
- Included Global.asax back into app.
- Build again
- Run again and now hits breakpoint in Application_Startup.
- Stopped vs web server again
- Made code change in route table to point to new page.
- Excluded Global again
- Built app again
- Ran app again - routes gone.
- Stopped vs web server again
- Included Global again
- Built app again
- Now - breakpoiont not hit again and old route is back

AM I going crazy?

Comment: Even though you said you reset your server, it still sounds like the application process is alive and kicking. Right click on your systray and ensure no development webservers are online.  They are represented by a little page and a cog. If they are, nuke 'em.

Comment: Yes - I know what the casinni icon looks like - thanks though. I even rebooted my box but the issue persists.

Comment: Perhaps a compilation issue? Is there a PrecompiledApp.config file?

Comment: No PrecompiledApp.config